# Probability that are solutions-modulo

Tags: number-theory

Consider the equation
$$ax \equiv b \pmod {15}$$

If we choose $a$ randomly from $1, \dots, 14$ and $b$ from $0,1, \dots, 14$, then which is the probability that the equation has  solution and which is the probability that the equation has exactly one solution ?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: I take that by *possibility* you mean *probability*.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes,that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The equation has a solution when $\gcd(a, 15)$ divides $b$, and it has a unique solution when $\gcd(a, 15) = 1$.  Can you proceed from here?

Comment: There are $\phi(15)=8$ solutions,for which: $gcd(a,15)=1$.But how can I find for how many numbers the condition $gcd(a,15)|b$ is satisfied?

Comment: You can always count. For instance, consider those $b$ that are coprime to 15, and see for how many $a$ you have a solution. Then consider those $b$ whose gcd with 15 is 3...